# How to make chart ignore filter in matrix headers?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to make a chart with indicators that are alsoe headers of  a matrix. My dataset has 4 variables (Date, Indicators  (A,B,C,D), Currency and Value). I have a matrix where the rows are the "Currency", the columns are the Indicators A and B and the values are "Value". In my chart, the x axis is Indicators (C and D), the legend is the "Currency" and the values is "Values". I want to make this chart ignore what is selected in the matrix columns but I need it to be responsive to the matrix rows (currency). I tried some filters but it didn work.

In the Fig 1 (link below)  we can see the screen if no filter is selected. And I want to select a currency (row) or a value in the matrix. But if I do it, my chat turns blank (Fig 2) where I want to see the values of C and D for the selected currency.
How can I do it?

All data and pibx are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vT0oQiRbkrG1AQAZHQmEL-5MwPs06I40)!

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the All() function, this restricts filters from affecting your measures